# How do I troubleshoot a problem syncing Google contacts to an iPad?

Tags: itunes, sync, ipad, google-contacts, macos

I use my MacBook Pro to sync content onto my wife's iPad.  (She doesn't have a computer.)  She doesn't want all my contacts from the Address Book app on my MBP.  But she does want her Google contacts on her iPad.

I've tried the following settings in iTunes:

[image]

I created a group in my address book called "Claire's" (and put just a couple contacts in it), since if one enables "Sync Address Book Contacts" one either has to select "All" or at least one group.  I've double-checked her email address in the dialog that comes up after pressing the "Configure" button.

But after syncing, only the couple contacts in the "Claire's" group are in the Contacts app on her iPad.  I've checked her Google contacts, and she has over 2000.  For some reason they're not syncing.

How do I find out why they're not?

I looked to see if I could just use an app to do the sync on the iPad, but couldn't find one with good ratings.  Do you have one to recommend so I can give up struggling with getting this working in iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the iPhone app [Sync in a Blink](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sync-in-a-blink/id290171875?mt=8).  It worked.